# R - get values of matrix using filter in other matrix

Tags: r, matrix

I have a matrix of the following type:

| c1 | c2 | c3 | c4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1234 | 123 | 124 | 134 |
| 234 | 23 | 14 | 124 |
| 1234 | 123 | 124 | 134 |
| 234 | 23 | 14 | 124 |

I have another matrix that tells me what are the cells that are ok:

| c1 | c2 | c3 | c4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 0 | 1 | 1 |
| 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 |
| 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 |

I want to get values of the 2 first columnes on table 1, that have a 1 on table 2:

| c1 | c2 |
| --- | --- |
| 1234 | 123 |
| 234 | 14 |
| 124 | 134 |
| 23 | 124 |

I can solve it with a for lop and head, but is there a better way?

Comment: It would be easier to help if you provide data in a reproducible format. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Comment: Isn't the example reproducible?!

Comment: No, a reproducible example is the one which we can copy-paste into our R session. We can't do that from your example. See how @GKi has created matrix `x` and `y` in his answer which can be copied directly. There are more tips here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can overwrite the non `1` with `NA` and use `apply` with `head`.

```
x[y!=1] <- NA
t(apply(x, 1, function(z) head(z[!is.na(z)], 2)))
#     [,1] [,2]
#[1,] 1234  123
#[2,]  234   14
#[3,]  124  134
#[4,]   23  124
```

Data:

```
x <- as.matrix(read.table(header=TRUE, text="c1     c2  c3  c4
1234    123     124     134
234     23  14  124
1234    123     124     134
234     23  14  124"))

y <- as.matrix(read.table(header=TRUE, text="c1     c2  c3  c4
1   1   1   1
1   0   1   1
0   0   1   1
0   1   0   1"))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do:

table1[table2$c1==1,]

`table2$c1==1` returns the c1 column that is 1, then map it to table1